# Multicell Table

Tags: html

Can anyone guide me to create a table like this. This has to be drawn dynamically.

First cell has the key of Map in java, which has a list of data.

Can we use tr inside td to get the three rows?

[image]

Comment: First figure out the static HTML.  If you know how to build one table, then dynamic variations on it aren't too hard.  Here's a tutorial to get you started: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/tables.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `colspan` and `rowspan` properties on `td` and `th` elements.

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdiaz/Y2uJu/)

Answer (score 3):

Please see code below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks... I should have used rowspan

Answer (score 1):

Another way by which you are able to get the desired table by embedding two tables and CSS

CSS

```
.t1{
 border:2px solid gray;
    border-right: none;
width:100%;
height:400px; 
padding:0;    
}
.t2{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;


}
.t2 td{
    width:33%;
    color:red;
     border-right:1px solid black;
     border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
.t2 .last td{
     border-bottom:none;
}
.c1{
    width: 25%;
    border-right: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    height:50%;
}
.c2{
    width:75%;
    border-left: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    height:50%;
}
​
```

HTML

```
<table class="t1">
<tr>
    <td class="c1">&nbsp;2</td>
    <td class="c2">
     <table class="t2">
         <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;1</td>
             <td>&nbsp;2</td>
             <td>&nbsp;3</td>         
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>         
         </tr>
         <tr class="last">
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>         
         </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="c1">&nbsp;3</td>
    <td class="c2">
    <table class="t2">
         <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>         
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>         
         </tr>
         <tr class="last">
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>         
         </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

The following is a [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) demo: http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/5ByVd/1/